# How to detect Bluetooth RFCOM channel crash from application android

Tags: android, crash, android-bluetooth, crashlytics, rfcomm

I have an application where sometimes Bluetooth channels are crashing from OS layer and then Bluetooth channel not start working again until phone rebooted. As its a OS layer crash I can't detect/handle it from my application. Here is the crash:

```
02-20 05:32:45.751: I/BluetoothServiceJni(20779): SOCK FLAG = 3 ***********************
02-20 05:32:45.751: E/BluetoothServiceJni(20779): Socket listen failed: 2
02-20 05:32:45.751: E/BluetoothAdapterService(1918354448)(20779): Failed to create socket channel
02-20 05:32:45.751: E/BluetoothSocketThread(762): Failed to listen for Bluetooth server socket connect.
02-20 05:32:45.751: E/BluetoothSocketThread(762): java.io.IOException: Error: -1
02-20 05:32:45.751: E/BluetoothSocketThread(762):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.createNewRfcommSocketAndRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:1245)
02-20 05:32:45.751: E/BluetoothSocketThread(762):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:1161)
02-20 05:32:45.751: E/BluetoothSocketThread(762):   at com.google.glass.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(BluetoothAdapter.java:148)
02-20 05:32:45.751: E/BluetoothSocketThread(762):   at com.google.glass.bluetooth.companion.BluetoothSocketThread.runInternally(BluetoothSocketThread.java:67)
02-20 05:32:45.751: E/BluetoothSocketThread(762):   at com.google.glass.bluetooth.companion.CompanionServerThread.run(CompanionServerThread.java:61)
02-20 05:32:45.761: W/BluetoothAdapter(762): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
```

My question, is there any way to detect Bluetooth channel OS related crash from my applicaiton.
Is it possible to detect the crash using fabric crashlytics native support or anything else?